# Eclipse "Append environment to native environment" appends empty lines in Run configuration

Tags: windows, eclipse, configuration, environment

To recreate:

1. create  a java project in Eclipse Mars.1.
2. create simple Java program.

   ```
   public class Test {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add some random variable in 'Environment' Tab of 'Run configuration' and choose the option 'Append Environment to native Environment' from bottom.
4. Run the Program. It will Display the PATH variable as multiple lines instead of a single variable.

   ```
   C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/bin/server;C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jre1.8.0_112/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;


   ;D:\eclipse\eclipse;
   ```

How to avoid this behavior? is this a Bug in Eclipse?